# Generating a confirmation code using java.util.Random class

Tags: java, random, web-applications

My web application is a test online store based on Spring framework in which I am trying to do user authentication by phone number using Twilio API to send a confirmation code on his phone number.

Should I generate a digit confirmation code in my web application using `java.util.Random` class to send it to the user's phone number? If it is not a good practice, how should I make it?

Comment: My web application is a test online store based on Spring framework in which i'am trying to do user authentication by phone number using Twilio API to send confirmation code on his phone number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should know that [Random](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Random.html) returns numbers that are not completely random, and thus using it for tasks that require a high level of security is not recommended. Instead, you should use [SecureRandom](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/security/SecureRandom.html) or other methods.

Citing the Javadoc documentation:

> Consider instead using SecureRandom to get a cryptographically secure pseudo-random number generator for use by security-sensitive applications.